# Solr: Deleting documents with angle brackets in id

Tags: python, solr, lucene

I'm trying to delete documents from a Solr index. I'm using pysolr and trying to delete them by id and by query. In both cases the operation fails with ids like this one: `cr-10.1002/(sici)1520-6688(199621)15:2<476::aid-pam7>3.3.co;2-2` with following error:

`pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: Unexpected character '4' (code 52) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,53]]`

https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters has no mention of escaping angle brackets at all. I tried it though, with no luck.

Any idea what I can do to delete these documents?

EDIT: updated the ID to match the error

Comment: This is probably an issue with pysolr and it not escaping the `<` in the XML generated to request the deletion. Try escaping it manually with `&lt;` before giving it to pysolr. Which method in pysolr are you using for deleting the document? (.. and I can't see a 4 referenced in your id at all, which might be weird)

Comment: Yeah, I already discovered that is the problem, because pySolr just formats the string with the ids or the query: `'<delete><query>%s</query></delete>' % q`. I solved the problem by using the JSON API, it doesn't need any escaping at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the JSON API like this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update' # update endpoint of the collection

ids_to_delete = ['a', 'b<c', 'd:e']
requests.post(url, json={ 'delete': ids_to_delete })
```